# MySQL Complex Query, user conversation

Tags: mysql

I have this query to get the last message between two users.

```
    SELECT  f.*
    FROM
            (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    messages a
                WHERE  (LEAST(a.sender, a.receiver), GREATEST(a.sender, a.receiver), a.timestamp) 
                        IN  (   
                                SELECT  LEAST(b.sender, b.receiver) AS x, 
                                        GREATEST(b.sender, b.receiver) AS y,
                                        MAX(b.timestamp) AS msg_time
                                FROM    messages b
                                GROUP   BY x, y
                            ) 
            ) f
    WHERE   :user_id IN (f.sender, f.receiver)
    ORDER   BY f.timestamp DESC
```

I got it here in SO, and it is a bit complex for me.

I need to modify it to get the last message only if `:user_id` has not deleted the conversation.

The table has 4 important fields: `sender, receiver, sender_deleted, receiver_deleted`.

When a user want to delete a conversation, i run a query to set the deleted fields to 1.

Example of table where user 4 has deleted the conversation:

```
sender   receiver    sender_deleted     receiver_deleted         message

  4         17             1                   0           user 4 to 17 message
  17        4              0                   1           user 17 to 4 message
```

I need to modify the above query so if `:user_id = 4`  it return empty, but if `:user_id = 17` return the last message sent.

I hope i explained well what i want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT  f.*
FROM
        (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    messages a
            WHERE  (LEAST(a.sender, a.receiver), GREATEST(a.sender, a.receiver), a.timestamp) 
                    IN  (   
                            SELECT  LEAST(b.sender, b.receiver) AS x, 
                                    GREATEST(b.sender, b.receiver) AS y,
                                    MAX(b.timestamp) AS msg_time
                            FROM    messages b
                            GROUP   BY x, y
                        ) 
        ) f
WHERE   (:user_id = f.sender AND f.sender_deleted != 1)
    OR (:user_id = f.receiver AND f.receiver_deleted != 1)
ORDER   BY f.timestamp DESC
```

Comment: I did a quick test, and seems working as i wanted. Thank you! I was going mad